# Visual Studio C# RDLC <sup> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc

I am pulling data from SQL Server into my VS2010 RDLC report. Everything is rendering properly, but I can't seem to get the `<sup>` tags to display. I changed the mode for the textbox to HTML, but I know `<sup>` is not available and is stripped out.

Example:
`<sup>99m</sup>Tc` is displaying as 99mTc (not superscripted)

Does anyone know another option that I can use for displaying the superscript tags? I have to have them on the report.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you're using does not support all HTML tags.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx

> The following is a complete list of tags that will render as HTML when defined as placeholder text:
>
> - Hyperlinks: <A href>
> - Fonts: <FONT>
> - Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>, <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>
> - Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>
> - List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>
>
> Any other HTML markup tags will be ignored during report processing. If the HTML that is represented by the expression in the placeholder text is not well formed, the placeholder is rendered as plain text. All HTML tags are case-insensitive.

Comment: Could you paste the relevant parts of the MSDN page into your answer, in case of link rot.

Comment: OK. I took the liberty of formatting the quoted text differently, because the site tried to syntax highlight it as it it were code.